# How to handle tapping local notification when app is terminated? flutter_local_notifications

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I want that when I click on my notification from the terminated state, it will work out a click on my notification. I have my NotificationService that handle my notifications, but
after i click on my notification nothing happens.
I call `.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails()` but even after that nothing happens when my notification is clicked.
Are there any options to handle notifications received from `flutterNotificationsPlugin` in a terminated state?

```
// My notifications class 
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {}

void onDidReceiveNotificationResponse(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
  navKey.currentState!.push(
    MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const CheckPage()),
  );
}

class NotificationService {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    AndroidNotificationChannel channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel',
    'High Importance Notifications',
    description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.',
    importance: Importance.high,
  );

  Future<void> initNotifications() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
    const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var initializationSettingsIOS =  const DarwinInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    await notificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
    await notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onDidReceiveNotificationResponse, onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: onDidReceiveNotificationResponse);

    FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
    if (initialMessage != null) {
      if (initialMessage.data['invoice_id'] != null) {
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1250))
            .then((value) => navKey.currentState!.push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => WareHouseSalesDetails(
                id: int.parse(initialMessage.data['id']),
                invoiceId: '${initialMessage.data['invoice_id']}',
              )),
        ));
      }
      if (initialMessage.data['moving_id'] != null) {
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1250))
            .then((value) => navKey.currentState!.push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => MovingDetailsPage(
                id: int.parse(initialMessage.data['id']),
                movingId: '${initialMessage.data['moving_id']}',
              )),
        ));
      }
    }

    await messaging.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification!.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        notificationsPlugin.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              channel.id,
              channel.name,
              channelDescription: channel.description,
              icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
      if (message.data['invoice_id'] != null) {
        navKey.currentState!.push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => WareHouseSalesDetails(
                id: int.parse(message.data['id']),
                invoiceId: '${message.data['invoice_id']}',
              )),
        );
      }
      if (message.data['moving_id'] != null) {
        navKey.currentState!.push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => MovingDetailsPage(
                id: int.parse(message.data['id']),
                movingId: '${message.data['moving_id']}',
              )),
        );
      }
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage? message) async {
      if (message!.data['invoice_id'] != null) {
        navKey.currentState!.push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => WareHouseSalesDetails(
                id: int.parse(message.data['id']),
                invoiceId: '${message.data['invoice_id']}',
              )),
        );
      }
      if (message.data['moving_id'] != null) {
        navKey.currentState!.push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => MovingDetailsPage(
                id: int.parse(message.data['id']),
                movingId: '${message.data['moving_id']}',
              )),
        );
      }
    });

    await messaging.requestPermission();
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      var APNS = await messaging.getAPNSToken();
    }
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  }
  Future scheduleNotification(
      {int id = 0,
      String? title,
      String? body,
      String? payLoad,
      required DateTime scheduledNotificationDateTime}) async {
    return
      notificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        id,
        title,
        body,
        payload: 'my_payload',
        tz.TZDateTime.from(
          scheduledNotificationDateTime,
          tz.local,
        ),
        const NotificationDetails(
          iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(
            presentAlert: true,
            presentBadge: true,
            presentSound: true,
          ),
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                'your channel id', 'your channel name',
                importance: Importance.max,
                priority: Priority.high,
                icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
                showWhen: false)),
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
            UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
  }
}
```